# node.js + mongoose connection and creation issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I just want to know if when I set a mongoose connection and I define some models, (previously adding their appropriate requires on app.js, or wathever), the model, if not exist, will be created automatically the first time when I run `node app.js?`

Is this kind of logic correct?

If not, do I have to create before my mongoDB collections, models and so on?

I was thinking to an automatic creation of the mongo db collection when I first run the app.js

Thanks!
Michele Prandina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schemas (and models) are a client-side (node.js) manifestation of your data model. A few things, like the indexes you've defined, are created upon first use (like saving a document for example). Nearly everything else is delay created, including collections.

If you want consistent behavior regarding your models (and their associated schemas), you'll need to make sure they're loaded prior to any access of the associated database. It doesn't really matter where you put them, as long as they are created/executed prior to usage. You might for example:

```
app.js

models\Cheese.js
      \Cracker.js
```

Then, in `app.js`:

```
var Cheese = require('Cheese.js');
var Cracker = require('Cracker.js');
```

Assuming, of course, you've exported the models:

```
model.exports = mongoose.model('Cheese', 
                       new mongoose.Schema({
                           name: String,
                           color: String 
                       })
                );
```

Comment: So, if I want to create and mantain, from the first execution, a DB, I have to export the model that are contained in that db?

Practical example:

`
//connect to local mongodb database
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test04');
`
Will no create the db unless if I export some models previously created.

Comment: As I said, the models are just a client side manifestation of a document stored in the database. If you want to use Mongoose, then using Models are the best way to access MongoDB. You don't have to `export` them, but you can only define them once.